# Laravel 5.4-Route [/dashboard] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Here is my route file

```
    Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/' , 'uses'=> 'loginController@getlogin']);
    Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses'=> 'loginController@postlogin']);

    Route::group(['middleware' =>['authen','roles']], function () {
    Route::get('/logout' ,['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=> 'loginController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=> 'dashboardController@dashboard']);
    });
```

when i try to login it shows   ***InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
Route [/dashboard] not defined.*** what should i do ??

Comment: Aren't you using `route()`or `action()` instead of `url()` ?

Comment: no but,  is it compulsory ??

Comment: i think this method also should work ,

Comment: I just checked the line in the `UrlGenerator.php` source code, you are using `route()` and this helper function should be use only with the route's name `url()` should be used in your case as you can see in the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url

Comment: So what should i do ??

Comment: i don't understand , what i have to do :(

Comment: replace `route()` by `url()`

Comment: which file ?? Route file or UrlGenerator.php

Comment: where you want to retrieve the url. It's seems to be in the loginController

Comment: if you don't mind , give me a small example :)

Comment: `url('/dashboard')` instead of `route('/dashboard')` simple as that.

Comment: oh , thanks you so much , i will check

Comment: whoops i face another problem "FatalErrorException in loginController.php line 34:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::url()"

Comment: Oh, you're using the class and not the helper method.
Use the method `to()`not the `route()`or `url()` method

Comment: you mean to('/dashboard') instead of url('/dashboard') ?

Comment: the problem is solved but i don't understand uses of to() , after using to() another problem is created "when i try to login it redirected to the same page mean (login page)"

Comment: this is another problem. It deals with authentication. My guess is, in the controller, conditions are not met to properly authenticate user, it stays as a guest. You're redirecting anyway the guest to dashboard, but the access is restricted to members only, so it fails back to login as normal.

Let me add an answer to this topic and this problem to solve it. One problem by topic

Comment: Please mark your topic as resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment, here is the solution :

Laravel use three differents concepts to redirects user (or even simply displays links) :

- by URL
- by Action
- by Route

## URL redirection

with the redirect helper shortcut

`redirect('/dashboard')`

or the appropriate method

`redirect()->to('/dashboard')`;

## Action redirection

`redirect()->action('dashboardController@dashboard')`

An action is one method of a controller.
For the redirection to work, a route has to point of this action.

## Route redirection

`redirect()->route('dashboard')`

For the redirection to work, the route has to have a name.
To assign a name to a route, you have to fluently chain the method `name`, like so :

`Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboardController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');`

## Your Case

In your case, you're redirection to a route instead of an url. Therefor you have two solution :

- adding a name to your route
- redirecting to url instead of a route